# Installing JDK Silently but JRE on different path

Tags: java, silent-installer

I want to install JDK Silently but want to install JRE on different path.  I am using this command, which installs JDK on given path and JRE inside the same path.  But I want to install JRE on different path, due to existing dependencies for diff path.

```
CALL D:\Installer\JAVA7\jdk-7u55-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" /INSTALLDIR="D:\Prereqs\Java-64\jdk" /L "C:\Users\Desktop\JAVA_64_SDK_INSTALL_Logs.txt"
```

tried giving one more parameter **/JREINSTALLDIR="D:\Prereqs\Java-64\jre"** but installer uses it for jdk installation path.

-Arun

Comment: I don't think that can work. It sounds like you need to first install the JDK, and then install a separate JRE. Why are you installing the JDK that way?

Comment: That was my last option...using JRE isntaller for JRE...I am just calling exe from a batch.

Comment: For Java 8 drop the slash on the JDK INSTALLDIR parameter:  CALL D:\Installer\JAVA8\jdk-8u144-windows-x64.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" INSTALLDIR="D:\Prereqs\Java-64\jdk" /L "C:\Users\Desktop\JAVA_64_SDK_INSTALL_Logs.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.
JDK when installed through UI, gives an option to change path for JDK installation.  Once JDK is installed, it gives an option to give path for JRE.

If we checked the JDK install path at this moment, we would find JRE installed under JDK Install path.  This is Private JRE.

Once you give the path for JRE to installer, it would install Public JRE.

If you check, the JRE folder inside the JDK path is 148 mb in size.  The Public JRE or normal JRE installation has same size 138 MB.

So using this command line should do the JOB as Manual UI install

```
start /w D:\Installer\JAVA7\jdk-7u55-windows-i586.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature,PublicjreFeature" /INSTALLDIR="D:\Prereqs\Java-64\jdk" /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE="D:\Prereqs\Java-64\jre" /L "C:\JAVA_64_JDK_JRE_INSTALL_Logs.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this one -

```
  jdk.exe /s /INSTALLDIRPUBJRE=C:\test\
```

i got the info from [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jdk-installation-windows.html), search the page for **Installing the JDK Silently**

Comment: I tried this.  Is Public JRE different from Normal JRE installation with SDK...I tried to compare the folders. There was 10 mb difference in size overall and some jars were different in size...so is this a problem?